# Show boundary of Möbius strip is the circle

Tags: algebraic-topology

The Möbius strip is the following polygon with opposite side identified as follows.

[image]

Now say I want to find the fundamental group of Mobius strip(I know it's $\mathbb{Z}$). I would usually use the Van Kampen as follows.

[image]

V is contractible, and U deformation retracts to the "boundary" of Mobius strip.

To see the boundary of the Mobius strip, I argue that since two vertices are identified by the gluing and 3 edges are distinct after gluing, the boundary must be a graph with Euler characteristic of -1, which would mean that the boundary is wedge of two circles, rather than one circle.

Where did I go wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: $U$ does not deformation retract to the boundary of the strip. Note that the glued edge is not part of the boundary.

Comment: @Karl ah so U does deformation retract to wedge of two circles?

Comment: I think so, if I understand your picture. $U$ deformation retracts to the boundary of the original rectangle, which is the boundary of $M$ (a circle) plus the extra edge $a$. You can turn this set into a wedge of two circles by shrinking $a$ to a point.

Answer (score 1):

Identifying the left and the right edge of the rectangle as indicated in your picture shows that the boundary of $M$ is a circle (which is obtained by gluing the upper and lower edge). However, the boundary does not contain the common image of the left and the right edge (except the endpoints). Thus your argument fails.

However, consider the horizotal line segment connecting the midpoints of the left and the right edge. Under our identification this gives the "middle" circle $C \subset M$.It is easy to see that $C$ is a strong deformation retract of $M$.